# react.js how to set up DefaultRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to set up route hierarchy. For now it looks like:

```
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: 'div',
  indexRoute: MainApp,
  childRoutes: [
    { path: '/', name: 'dashboard', component: MainApp},
    { path: 'quiz', name: 'quiz', component: QuizApp}
  ]
};
```

If I click on link with `href="#quiz"` I can see `QuizApp`. But jus loading home page I can see only what I wrote in index.html file. How to set up properly DefaultRouter?

Here are dependencies:

```
"react": "^0.14.0-beta3",
"react-dom": "^0.14.0-beta3",
"react-redux": "^1.0.1",
"react-router": "^1.0.0-rc3",
"redux": "^1.0.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found out, that I cannot just set the name of component, I have to set an object with at least the 'component' property:

```
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: 'div',
  indexRoute: {component: MainApp},
  childRoutes: [
    { path: '/', name: 'dashboard', component: MainApp},
    { path: 'quiz', name: 'quiz', component: QuizApp}
  ]
};
```

Comment: React Router 1.0 is not using named Routes anymore, see the [Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#route-config)